# How to catch errors in Function returning KeyValuePair(Of Date, Date)

Tags: vb.net, function, date, error-handling

I have a function returning `KeyValuePair(Of Date, Date)`

To catch errors, I've wrote:

```
Function KVP_Dates(ByVal StartDate As Date) As KeyValuePair(Of Date, Date)
    Try
        'Do stuff
    Catch ex as exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

But both `Date` and `KeyValuePair(Of Date, Date)` aren't nullable and, anyway, if I use:

```
Dim D As Date = KVP_Dates(Date.Today).Value
```

I don't get error but `D = 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`

What can I return on error, so to know if there was an error?

Comment: You could implement it as a pair of methods: `CanGetKVPDates() As Boolean`, then if true then go get them. With so such redacted (like why there is a Try/Catch) its hard to say if there is an better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the `KeyValuePair` in a [**`Nullable(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a class designed to hold value types (also known as *structures*) and let you assign **null** to them.

```
Function KVP_Dates(ByVal StartDate As Date) As Nullable(Of KeyValuePair(Of Date, Date))
    Try
        'Do stuff
    Catch ex as exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Then of course you have to check if the entire KVP is null, not just the date itself (attempting to access the date will throw an exception if the KVP is null).

```
Dim KVP = KVP_Dates(Date.Today)
If KVP IsNot Nothing Then
    'KVP is not null.
    Dim D As Date = KVP.Value.Value

Else
    'KVP is null, an error occurred.
End If
```

As you see though, you have to get two different `Value` properties: The value of the `Nullable` and the value of the `KeyValuePair`.